# Problem with installing kali linux on macbook pro retina 2015

Tags: boot, dual-boot, macbook

I can't intall kali linux on my macbook pro retina. I want to have dual boot but my mac doesn't see pendrive with kali. In recovery i can't switch secure boot because there are not option like that.
Please help